# How to identify Cordova app security vulnerabilities?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, google-play-console, android-security

Google removed our app from Google Play because

> it uses software that contains security vulnerabilities and violates
>   our Malicious Behavior policy.

So they ask us to:

> Fix all of the security vulnerabilities listed in your Play Console
>   that have past deadlines

However, this is a Cordova app that merely opens a certain url. So how would I know what exactly is considered a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open google play console and you should see an "alerts" item in the left sidebar that will tell you what the problem is. In my case I had an app using an old version of jQuery, so I needed to update that and check for any reversions

Comment: hi, i am also facing same issue 
For example, your app contains an Intent Redirection issue which can allow malicious apps to access private app components or files.

androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult
can you please help me solve the problem.